# How to calculate slope of the line

Tags: line, diff, lm, quantmod

I am trying to calculate the slope of the line for a 50 day EMA I created from the adjusted closing price on a few stocks I downloaded using the getSymbols function.

My EMA looks like this :

```
getSymbols("COLUM.CO")
COLUM.CO$EMA <- EMA(COLUM.CO[,6],n=50)
```

This gives me an extra column that contains the 50 day EMA on the adjusted closing price. Now I would like to include an additional column that contains the slope of this line. I'm sure it's a fairly easy answer, but I would really appreciate some help on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this is with rolling least squares regression. `rollSFM` does a fast and efficient job for computing the slope of a series.  It usually makes sense to look at the slope in relation to units of price activity in time (bars), so `x` can simply be equally spaced points.

The only tricky part is working out an effective value of `n`, the length of the window over which you fit the slope.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
AAPL$EMA <- EMA(Ad(AAPL),n=50)
# Compute slope over 50 bar lookback:
AAPL <- merge(AAPL, rollSFM(Ra = AAPL[, "EMA"], 
                            Rb = 1:nrow(AAPL), n = 50))
```

The column labeled `beta` contains the rolling window value of the slope (`alpha` contains the intercept, `r.squared` contains the R2 value).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering if it'd be possible to only add the column beta as an additional column? (and not include the alpha and rsquared). Thanks

Comment: To only select `beta` ( the second column of the rollSFM object): 
 `rollSFM(Ra = AAPL[, "EMA"], Rb = 1:nrow(AAPL), n = 50)[,2] ` or 
`rollSFM(Ra = AAPL[, "EMA"], Rb = 1:nrow(AAPL), n = 50)[,’beta’]`

Comment: Thanks hvollmeier, much appreciated!